# Problems with print statement in python

Tags: python, function, loops, turtle-graphics

I am having problem with the print statement in python when using the turtle module.

Okay so when I run the f.f.g code:
The word "yes" and the y coordinate of the turtle is printed but the yes at the end is not printed. Only after I close the turtle screen does the "yes" get printed again as well as the y coordinate printed again. How the code should work is that all the mentioned above is printed even whilst the turtle screen is still open.

```
import turtle

def drawSquare(length, turtle):
    for i in range(4):
        if (i == 0):
            print("yes" + str(turtle.ycor()), end = "yes")#Only end with yes after turtle screen is closed.
        turtle.forward(length)
        if (i == 0):
            print(turtle.ycor(), end = "\n\n")#Only prints after turtle screen is closed.       
        turtle.left(90)

sc = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
drawSquare(100, t)
sc.exitonclick()
```

I need some info on what's going on. All help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I am using Python 3.2.1

Comment: What if you run the script with `python3 -u`?

Comment: Do I have to download it. It would take a long time.

Comment: How do you currently invoke your program?

Comment: I am also experiencing problem with .forward function from the turtle module. In some case the lines end up jagged.

Comment: Does `end="yes\n"` work better? The output may be buffered until you print a newline.